# File upload condition not working how I want it to work

Tags: javascript, php

I have a script that detects if the file upload contains a file or not. So if a user  press the upload button it will tell the user if the file upload contains a

file or not but the problem I can't figure out is, why am I getting an error when I try to upload with no file I assumed it would generate the if condition saying

No file detected in upload

but instead it gives me this error

```
Notice: Undefined index: image in etc../x.php on line 3
```

and for some reason it still executes the else condition combine with the above error

```
Detected
```

It does not makes sense to me. What am I doing wrong? How can I get it to produce the right condition without no errors?

Here is my code

**index.php**

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    
document.getElementById('upload').addEventListener("click",executeAjax);

function executeAjax(){

var xhr= new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
    
    if(xhr.readyState === 4){
        document.getElementsByClassName('output-container')[0].innerHTML= xhr.responseText;
    }
}
    
    var data = new FormData();
    
  //Var structure
  var image=  document.getElementById('image').files[0];

  data.append('image',image);
 
  xhr.open('POST','x');
  xhr.send(data);
}

});
</script>

<input id='image' type='file'>

<button id='upload'>Upload</button>

<div class='output-container'><div>
```

**x.php**

```
<?php

if($_FILES['image']['error']  == 4)
{
echo 'No file detected in upload';
}
else{
    echo 'Detected';
}
?>
```

Documentation for value 4 [link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Comment: you want to do an `isset()` on the `$_FILES['image']`, like `isset($_FILES['image'])`, that is how you should perform your check to see if a file is provided. Directly going to using `$_FILES['image']` means you are already sure there is a file there.

Comment: I had a feeling that would work but I guess it's the JavaScript' new form method that don't exactly simulate what the <form> can do I originally had this set up using the form tag on the same page as index.php and it worked perfectly with if($_FILES['image']['error']  == 4)  but am ma make a new post soon on a different topic involving issues with PHP'S $_FILES  method with JS new form method but thanks for your response.

Comment: @coderodour how can I reward you for best answer you deserve some reward on your helpful advice? Is it possible to reward a person for best answer in the comments section?

Comment: I do not think so, it feels rewarding enough to have helped and you coming back to acknowledge/confirm it. Thank YOU! Good Luck.